# Finding MIN in UNION Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table with three columns, Price1, Price2 and Price3. For each price column, there is also a dedicated amount column, Amount1, Amount2, and Amount3.
There are also the column ID and Batch.

What I want to achieve is to find the minimum value of **all the three Amount columns combined**.

The following is the SQL I use now

```
Select
MIN(Q.Min_Size)  As Min_Min_Size 
From
    (Select
         Min("Archive"."Amount1") As Min_Size
     From
         "Archive"
     Where
         "Archive"."ID" = '123' And
         "Archive"."Price1" = 7.4 And
         "Archive"."Batch" > 2986 And
         "Archive"."Batch" < 6243) Q
Union 
Select
    Q.Min_Size
From
    (Select
         Min("Archive"."Amount2") As Min_Size
     From
         "Archive"
     Where
         "Archive"."ID" = '123' And
         "Archive"."Price2" = 7.4 And
         "Archive"."Batch" > 2986 And
         "Archive"."Batch" < 6243) Q
Group By
    Q.Min_Size
Union 
Select
    Q.Min_Size
From
    (Select
         Min("Archive"."Amount3") As Min_Size
     From
         "Archive"
     Where
         "Archive"."ID" = '123' And
         "Archive"."Price3" = 7.4 And
         "Archive"."Batch" > 2986 And
         "Archive"."Batch" < 6243) Q
Group By
    Q.Min_Size
```

With this statement I have three lines, the first with the minimum of the column "Amount1", the second with the minimum of the column "Amount2" and the third with the minimum of the column "Amount3". What I want to achieve instead is **one line only with the minimum of the three**

**EDIT**

I have found this new statement that works but I was wondering if there is a better one.

```
Select
    Min(Least("Archive"."Amount1", "Archive"."Amount2", "Archive"."Amount3")) As MinAmount
From
    "Archive"
Where
    ("Archive"."ID" = '123' And
        "Archive"."Price1" = 7.4 And
        "Archive"."Batch" > 2986 And
        "Archive"."Batch" < 6243) Or
    ("Archive"."ID" = '123' And
        "Archive"."Batch" > 2986 And
        "Archive"."Batch" < 6243 And
        "Archive"."Price2" = 7.4) Or
    ("Archive"."ID" = '123' And
        "Archive"."Batch" > 2986 And
        "Archive"."Batch" < 6243 And
        "Archive"."Price3" = 7.4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [`least()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) function: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/7aj57Qx5)

```sql
SELECT min(least("Archive"."Amount1", 
                 "Archive"."Amount2", 
                 "Archive"."Amount3")) AS "Min_Size"
FROM "Archive"
WHERE "Archive"."ID" = '123'
AND 7.4 IN("Archive"."Price1",
           "Archive"."Price2",
           "Archive"."Price3")
AND "Archive"."Batch" > 2986
AND "Archive"."Batch" < 6243;
```

Comment: Looks like I aswered about the same time you were adding your edit. The conditions can be shortened a bit, but that's pretty much it

Comment: With my PG seems to be working with 7.4=ANY(array["Archive"."Price1",
        "Archive"."Price2",
        "Archive"."Price3"])

Comment: You're right, the plain comma separated value list is `IN` syntax. `ANY()` takes either the array or a subquery returning a single column. I added the correction and a demo

Comment: What if I want to add to the select also the correspondent "Archive"."Batch"?

Comment: `select batch, least(amount1,amount2,amount3) from... order by 2 limit 1`. I updated [the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/7aj57Qx5) adding an example.